# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' when getting object's id

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get exact object ("Tweet"), because I want to use it's info. Here it is how:

Template:

```
{% for tweet in tweets %}
    {{tweet.text}} - {{tweet.date}}
    <form action="#" method="get">
        <input type="submit" class="" value="Favourite" name="favourite">
        <input type="hidden" name="idtweet" id="{{tweet.id}}">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Views:

```
if request.GET.get('favourite'):
        tweet_id = request.GET['idtweet']
        tweet_object = Tweet.objects.get(id=tweet_id)
```

However, I get this error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given the `idtweet` input a value: you're putting the value into the id attribute, for some reason, instead of the value attribute.

Note however that favouriting, since it modifies data, should be a POST, not a GET.

Answer (score 0):

Following Daniel's answer, what's happen in Django internal is :

```
 >>> int('')
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I suggest you to use:

- `request.GET.get('idtweet', 0)`, for get bad ID if inexistent
- [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) for clean filtering

Or a [Django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) for simply validate forms.